# How does GHC runtime deal with file I/O?

Tags: c, haskell, ghc

Some papers on GHC runtime internals mention that it uses epoll/kqueue/poll to detect whether a file descriptor is ready to read/write.

I can understand how it's done for socket I/O. But what about disk file access?  The poll syscall doesn't work with ordinary files, only with socket I/O; true?

The only option I can imagine here is using a thread pool for blocking syscalls, one thread-per-request...

Comment: On POSIX platforms (like Linux, OSX and BSD) a descriptor is a small integer, and can either be a file, a pipe, a socket, or something completely different. And they all support mostly the same support functions, like polling.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg poll on disk file fd will always return that it's ready for IO, while actually it would block.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm sorry but that is BS. Doesn't matter how much are you trying to read, it may block (even with O_NONBLOCK) anyway.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: A regular file will *always* poll as being ready, even if reading one byte would block.

Comment: And BSD's kqueue works for both sockets and files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the unthreaded RTS, the whole runtime will block. In the threaded RTS, it will do safe foreign calls like this via thread pool, so the capability will not block.